# Visualizing objects in rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Guys,
i am completely new to ROS and trying to learn how to get things done. I am trying to model an environment where I have two objects and the pr2 in my world. The launch file is the following:

```
 <!-- send urdf to param server -->
 <param name="object1" textfile="/home/x/ros_workspace/project/objects/urdf/object1.urdf" />
 <param name="object2" textfile="/home/ros_workspace/project/objects/urdf/object2.urdf" />

 <!-- push urdf to factory and spawn robot in gazebo -->
 <node name="spawn_object1" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param object1 -x 3.0 -y 3.0 -z 0.1  -model object1" respawn="false" output="screen" />
 <node name="spawn_object2" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param object2 -x 2.75 -y 3.5 -z 0.25  -model object2" respawn="false" output="screen" />
```

My objects get correctly spanwned and I can visualize them in gazebo, but they do not appear on rviz. How would I see the objects in rviz?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12110/visualizing-objects-in-rviz/) by [zamboni](https://answers.ros.org/users/1449/zamboni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to upload URDF model of your object to ROS parameter server (object1, object2) - it's already in your launch file.

Then you have to add its display in RVIZ - type robot model (set robot description to "object1"). For object2 you have to add next robot model display.

And finally publish transformations via TF - sample code for this task is [here](http://pastebin.com/hcipigtf). It's reading (one) object position from Gazebo and publishing transformation between world frame, robot base_link and object link.

---

Originally posted by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) with karma: 704 on 2011-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1